# Unable to display image from web on blackberry device

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I developed simple code to display an image and title on blackberry screen, but I am not able to display anything (but if I tested for title only it is working).

My requirement is to display image with title in a list.

I have followed [this link for fetching image from image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310572/download-and-show-image-on-a-blackberry)

and here my code in drawlistrow method:

```
public void drawListRow(ListField list, Graphics g, int index, int y, int w) 
        {
            String text = (String)listElements.elementAt(index);
            Bitmap image =GetImage.connectServerForImage("http://toucheradio.com/toneradio/iphone/toriLite/toriLive.png");
            g.drawLine(0, y, w, y);

            g.drawText(text, 150, y, 60, w);
            g.drawBitmap(0,y,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),image,0,0);
        }
```

What could be  the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And please check the image height and width if its big than your screen resolution, then you have to crop or enlarge the image you are getting. Give some x axis to the drawBitmapMethod i have just giving you the idea like below you can implement.

```
g.drawBitmap(340, y, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image, 0, 0);
```

Comment: i got  requirement ,if append this(";deviceside=true") to at the end of   my image web url like this   imageweburl+";deviceside=true",then it is working

Comment: i will suggest you to read this http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/deviceside-true/td-p/54164